# ArrayInitLexer cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I want to use antlr4 in a java project in eclipse. I have finished prepare work, such as install ANTLR4 in eclipse market, wrote g4 file, add antlr-4.7-complete.jar to build path, and make target/generated-sources/antlr4 as source folder.
But in main java function, eclipse told me **'ArrayInitLexer' cannot be resolved to a type**
here's my g4 file.

```
grammar ArrayInit;

init : '{' value (',' value)* '}' ;

value : init
      | INT
      ;
INT : [0-9]+;
WS : [\t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

It's correct, I test it in command line, and it can return me a parse tree.
here's my project structure:
[image]

and in the Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        Lexer lexer = new ArrayInitLexer(input); //ArrayInitLexer couldn't resolve
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ANTLRParser parser = new ArrayIntParser(tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have imported the class using the Import keyword? Is the lib folder part of  the classpath?

Comment: I use import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*; it seems not work. How to test is lib folder part of the classpath? thanks.

Comment: `ArrayInitLexer` is in Default package not in the package you are importing

Comment: You mean that ArrayInitLexer isn't add in the source folder, like target/.../antlr4. But It seems I can't add this default folder as a source folder in eclipse. I just tried. Or It's already under the source folder.

Comment: Oh, I See That, I partly solved it by coping all java files under default package to a new package. Then I can import it.

Comment: Thanks, @Jens. btw, Do you know how to auto generate java files under a package by antlr?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/683

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll take a look.